# xcode paths are not aliased in build settings

Tags: ios, build, xcode4, settings

In my Xcode project the build setting show up without substitution. For instance, Intermediate Build Files Path is displayed as $(SYMROOT) instead of the path that SYMROOT is an alias for. The same is true of my other Build Setting paths.

The project builds fine. I wonder if either these variables have not been set for some reason, or is there a display preference that tells Xcode to show them without substitution.

I've searched the web without finding any answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: In project navigator select your Project so that the Build Settings are displayed in the editor. In the top menu bar select Editor/Show Values.

Simple but I had no idea where to find that.